# make a layout widget to be floating ouside of mainwindow pyqt5

Tags: python, layout, pyqt5, floating

everyone.
I want to float a widget inside a layout of a main-window.
the widget is disappered from layout but not displayed on screen
As you can see from following code. I floated  two labels 'lbl_title' and 'lbl_icon'
they seems to be floated but not displayed on screen.
Here comes my code.
If you loose commented line, then the lbl_icon and title is removed from layout but not are shown on my screen

```
    from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir, Qt, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaContent, QMediaPlayer
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QFileDialog, QHBoxLayout, QLabel,
        QPushButton, QSizePolicy, QSlider, QStyle, QVBoxLayout, QWidget)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QWidget, QPushButton, QAction,QGridLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon,QPixmap
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class CommonLessonItem(QWidget):

    def __init__(self,parent):

        super(CommonLessonItem,self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.lbl_title = QLabel(self)
        self.lbl_description = QLabel(self)
        self.lbl_icon = QLabel(self)
        self.__initUI()
        self.isChild = False

    def __initUI(self):
        
        #set layout
        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lbl_title,0,0,1,19)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lbl_icon,0,19,1,1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lbl_description,1,0,1,20)
        self.lbl_icon.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint|Qt.Window)
        self.lbl_icon.move(100,100)
        self.lbl_title.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint|Qt.Window)
        self.lbl_title.move(100,100)
        
        #initialize info
        self.setInfo("Title","Description",None)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)


    def setInfo(self,title,description,iconPath):
        self.lbl_title.setText(title)
        self.lbl_description.setText(description)
        if(iconPath is not None):
            self.lbl_icon.setPixmap(QPixmap(iconPath))
    def moveEvent(self,event):
        super().moveEvent(event)
        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = CommonLessonItem(None)
    # mw.setSize(10,200)
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I need your help.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: I edited my qestion

Comment: What are the Common*? You will understand that if you do not have the code of those classes then it is impossible to reproduce your code

Comment: Oh. I am very sorry. I changed my code already

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a widget becomes a top level window by setting the parent to `None` or, like in your case, setting the `Window` flag (but I wouldn't suggest that approach) `show()` must be called.

As explained in [`windowFlags`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop):

> **Note:** This function calls setParent() when changing the flags for a window, causing the widget to be hidden. You must call show() to make the widget visible again..

Add `self.lbl_icon.show()` and `self.lbl_title.show()` *after* changing their window state.